# Returning NoneType vs. returning "" in re.search

Tags: python, regex, search

I did some searching and did not see this specific issue, but let me know if it's a duplicate.

I wrote a function called find_results that searches a string for a separator character and then returns anything between the separator and a new line:

```
def find_results(findme, separator, string):
    linelist=string.split('\n')
    for line in linelist:
        if re.search(findme, line):
            #Split based on the separator we were sent, but only on the first occurrance
            line = line.split(separator, 1)
            return line[1].strip()
        #End if line.find
    #end for loop
    return ""
#end find_results
```

The function works great, but I'm sure there's a more Pythonic way to accomplish the same task, and frankly I feel a little silly calling a custom function for such a simple thing.

I  recently learned how to use Sets in regular expression, so I've been able to replace the function with an re.search call in some cases.  If the separator is a colon, for example:

```
re.search("Preceeding\ Text:(.*)$", string).group(1)
```

The problem with this is that when there are no results, I get a "NoneType" crash because there is no attribute "group" on a "NoneType".  I can check the results with an if or try / except statement, but that defeats the purpose of the change from using find_results to begin with.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to suspend the NoneType crash and just have it return "" (blank)?
- Is there a different one-line way to accomplish this?
- If I have to use a custom function, is there a more Pythonic (and less embarrassing) way to write it?

Comment: You could change the regex into one which always matches. `"foo"` can be matched by `"foo|"` which falls back to matching nothing if "foo" is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [str.partition](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
def find_results(findme, separator, s):
    tgt=s[s.find(findme):]
    return tgt.partition(separator)[2]

>>> find_results('Text', ':', 'Preceding Text:the rest')  
'the rest'
>>> find_results('Text', ';', 'Preceding Text:the rest')  
''
>>> find_results('text', ':', 'Preceding Text:the rest')  
''
```

Since partition always returns a 3 element tuple with the final element being `''` for not found, that can probably even be your one liner:

```
>>> s='Preceding Text:the rest'
>>> s[s.find('Text'):].partition(':')[2]
'the rest'
>>> s[s.find('Text'):].partition(';')[2]
''
```

If the `findme` part or `separator` parts are only useful if they are regular expressions, use re.split with try/except:

```
def find_re_results(findme, separator, s):
    p1=re.compile(findme)
    p2=re.compile(separator)
    m=p1.search(s)
    if m:
        li=p2.split(s[m.start():], maxsplit=1)
    else:
        return ''
    try:
        return li[1]
    except IndexError:
        return ''
```

Demo:

```
>>> find_re_results('\d+', '\t', 'Preceding 123:;[]\\:the rest') 
''
>>> find_re_results('\d+', '\W+', 'Preceding 123:;[]\\:the rest') 
'the rest'
>>> find_re_results('\t', '\W+', 'Preceding 123:;[]\\:the rest') 
''
```

Comment: This is the answer I knew was out there, but didn't know how to articulate.  Thanks Dawg.  PS - I think "preceeding" is what you meant in your example text.  Sorry to be a nazi.

Comment: Thanks for the homonym correction. Yes I did mean 'precede' rather than 'proceed'. Here is a spelling correction: It is "preceding" not "preceeding" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The one liner you are looking for is:

```
return re.findall(r'Preceeding\ Text:(.*)$', text) or ''
```

If there are no matches, `findall()` will return an empty list, in that case you want the result to be `''` which is what the or will do.

Don't use `string` as a variable name, it conflicts with the built-in string module.

Answer (score 0):

re.findall is a great way for searching for multiple instances of a pattern:

```
r = re.compile("^[^:]*:(.*)$", re.MULTILINE)
r.findall("a: b\nc: d")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one-line code you want. Functional programming is really amazing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import re

if __name__ == '__main__':

    findme= 'abc'
    sep = ','
    stringa = '1,2,3,4,5,abc'


    print map(lambda line, findme=findme, sep=sep: line.split(sep, 1)[1].strip() if re.search(findme, line) else "", stringa.split('\n'))
```